# Как перехватить ввод/вывод консольного приложения в Java?

Tags: java, консоль

Пытаюсь написать графическую оболочку для консольной программы (модификация сервера Minecraft - http://u.to/-aJ6AQ). Подскажите, как из моей программы запустить стороннее консольное приложение и отобразить его вывод в моей программе в JTextPane (или хотя бы вывести через System.out.printin, в текстовое поле я и сам запихну))? Ну и, если знаете, подскажите, как вводить команды в это консольное приложение через мою программу. Вот что пока у самого получилось:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar  \"путь_к_файлу.jar\"");
String line;
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
```

Пишет только две первые строчки и останавливается (хотя должно быть больше...)

---

Попробовал сделать с ProcessBuilder:

```
    String javaBin = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "javaw";
    ArrayList command = new ArrayList();
    command.add(javaBin);
    RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    Object[] tmpOptsObj = RuntimemxBean.getInputArguments().toArray();
    for (Object s : tmpOptsObj) {
        command.add(s.toString());
    }
    command.add("-jar");
    command.add("C:\\SERVER\\craftbukkit.jar");
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    try {
        final Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Program stopped!");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Вывод консоли:
run:
174 recipes
27 achievements

Тут очень много символов ">"

ПОСТРОЕНИЕ ОСТАНОВЛЕНО (общее время: 28 секунд)

Comment: В общем вроде добился того, что нужно. Просто добавил программу, которую нужно запускать, в качестве библиотеки и сделал запуск нужного класса из моей программы с отслеживанием Logger'a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можно использовать [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/), который предоставляет возможности для работы с stdin, stdout, stderr.
2. Можно использовать `Process` (ваш выбор). В этом случае немного проще работать с `ProcessBuilder`, а не с `Runtime().exec`.

```
String line;
BufferedReader reader;

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");

OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

// Пишем в stdin
line = "..." + "\n";
stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
stdin.flush();
stdin.close();

// Читаем из stdout
reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
  // ...
}
reader.close();

// Читаем из stderr
reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stderr));
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
  // ...
}
reader.close();
```

[Execute an external program](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html).

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать...

Comment: Нет, не получается... Эта консольная программа - модификация сервера Minecraft - http://u.to/-aJ6AQ. Можете попробовать сами? Может я что-то делаю не так...

Comment: Это не важно какая это программа. Описанный подод должен работать.. правда возможно следует объединить stderr и stdout (есть для этого метод.. mergeЧтоТоТам) или читать параллельно двумя потоками одновременно (редко нужно на самом деле)

Comment: А эта консольная программе от Вас ввода не ждет ? Просто Вы можете не видеть приглашения к вводу, т.к. оно "застряло" в буфере пайпа. Такое бывает, если программа не делает flush. С терминалом все идет, а с пайпом нет.

Comment: Нет, ввода она может ждать только после полного запуска сервера, о чём, разумеется, напишет в логе... Я нашёл простое подобие того, что пытаюсь написать сам. Попробую разобраться, как это там работает.

Comment: Несколько лет назад я видел подобную проблему на HP-UX. 

Когда вывод утилиты (написана на C) был небольшой, все работало (Java программа успешно читала его, а утилита завершалась), а когда большой (десятки килобайт (?)) то обе подвисали. 

Аккуратно так и не решили. В результате стали формировать Shell команду с перенаправлением вывода во временный файл (в Java формировали имя файла, командную строку  и запускали /bin/sh с ней), а потом читали и удаляли этот файл. 

Но, (это может оказаться существенно) C-программа ничего не читала, только параметры командной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Перенаправление вывода программы + изменение системного вывода:

```
final PrintStream out = new PrintStream ( new File ( "out.txt" ) ) ;
System.setOut ( out ) ;
System.setErr ( out ) ;

try
{
    String line ;
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ( "/bin/echo abc" ) ;
    final BufferedReader ir = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( p.getInputStream () ) ) ;
    final BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( p.getErrorStream () ) ) ;
    while ( null != (line = ir.readLine ()) )
    {
        System.out.println ( line ) ;
    }
    ir.close () ;
    while ( null != (line = bre.readLine ()) )
    {
        System.out.println ( line ) ;
    }
    bre.close () ;
    p.waitFor () ;

    System.out.println ( "out" ) ;
    throw new Exception ( "err" ) ;
}
catch ( final Exception err )
{
    System.err.println ( err.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
}
```